# casting between short,int,long,double,float in Java

Tags: java, types, casting, int, double

As i understand, when you cast between 2 of these types with an arithmetic operation in Java, for example double + int, the result will be as the bigger type (meaning in this example, the result will be double). What happens when you make an arithmetic operation on 2 types with the same size? what will int + float and long + double give? since int and float are 4 bytes each, and long and double are 8 bytes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is all specified by the *binary numeric promotion* rules in the JLS.  From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
>      conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>      both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>        to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>        to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
>
> After the type conversion, if any, value set conversion (§5.1.13) is
>   applied to each operand.
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, / and % (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and -
>     (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)
> - The integer bitwise operators &, ^, and | (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)

("value set conversion" is about mapping between floating-point representations.)

Answer (score 2):

`int` + `float` will give you `float` (note that you'll have to cast result to `float` because `double` is used by default). `long` + `double` will give you `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Still going to return the `"bigger"` type that can hold the entirely value. In your specific question

if you make a + between a int and a float the return will be a float
   and long + double returns a double,

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the additive operators `+` and `-` is defined in by [15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) of the JLS. It states that it first performs a binary numeric promotion:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operand.

This in turns is defined by [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). In substance, for primitives:

- If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Answer (score 0):

There are two an interesting FAQ on type conversion that can be found in: http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JAVA-Type-Conversion-Casting

http://myhowto.org/java/60-understanding-the-primitive-numeric-type-conversions-in-java/

Answering your questions on two types of the same size, the return value is of the type with the biggest precision.

Try the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=1;
    float f=2.5f;
    long l=10;
    double d=3.74;
    System.out.println(i+f);
    System.out.println(f+i);
    System.out.println(l+d);
    System.out.println(d+l);
}
```

You will see that the results are 3.5 and 13.74, which are a float and a double, respectively (tested in Netbeans 6.9 and java 1.6).

Answer (score 0):

A gotcha of this "promotion" is that a `long` + `float` will "widen" to using a float.

e.g.

```
System.out.println(1111111111111111111L + 0.0f);
System.out.println(1111111111111111111L + 0.0);
```

prints

```
1.11111113E18
1.11111111111111117E18
```

When dealing with long and float, you may not get a wider type and can lose more precision than you might expect.

Comment: IMHO, Java should have forbidden type combinations with many operators, allowed implicit conversion from `double` to `float` in most cases where the destination type is clearly `float`, since such conversions would almost always yield expected behavior, and disallowed implicit conversions from `float` to `double`, since such conversions are often wrong (e.g. `double OneTenth=1.0f/10.0f;` should have squawked IMHO but doesn't).  I wouldn't mind implicit conversion from `long` to `float` if the resulting `float` couldn't interact directly with other types.

Comment: @supercat I agree, but the other way around `double` has much more precision which why conversion from float to double is ok. (You can convert back without loss) If you convert double to float and back again, you can lose precision which is why it not safe.  In general, I would avoid using float as it is not useful in 99% of cases.

Comment: There are a number of axioms implicit type conversions could (and IMHO should) satisfy to minimize "astonishment"; I just wrote a blog entry at http://supercatnet.blogspot.com/2013/09/axioms-of-implicit-type-conversion.html and would like your feedback.  To me, one of the most important is that if `t` is type `T`'s best representation of some abstract quantity *x* and an implicit conversion exists from `T` to `U`, then `(U)t` should be one of U's best representations of that same *x*.  Another is that `(U)t==t` should not return false for any combination of types and values.  Either...

Comment: @supercat I agree. `(double) 0.1f == 0.1f` is true.  `(float) 0.1 == 0.1` is false.

Comment: ...direct comparison between the types should be forbidden (if the cast is lossy in *either* direction), or else the cast should throw an exception (if `U` has no representation for *x*, not even a bad one).  To my mind, if there's only one thing a programmer could plausibly intend a construct to mean and its meaning would match that intention, it should be be expressible directly; otherwise, the programmer should have to write the expression to make his intention clearer. Does that seem like a good philosophy of language design?

Comment: @supercat In most cases where precision is losy, an explict cast is required.  The only exceptions I know of are int/long => float/double. IMHO these should require explicit casts as well.  Personally I thing `int b,c; int a = b * c` should return a cast as `b * c` can overflow silently otherwise. i.e. either `long a = b * c; // doesn't overflow` or `int a = (int) (b * c);`

Comment: Would you like to discuss this either at my blog or in chat?  I'd like your feedback on what I wrote there.  As for your scenario, if I were writing the rules and couldn't make `long a=b*c;` equivalent to `long a=(long)b*c;` I'd make the language require a typecast to `int` (e.g. `long a=(int)(b*c);` by e.g. tagging operator with an attribute forbidding its return value from being used in a place where a programmer might be expecting a `long`.

Comment: @supercat and only overflow when the developer has indicated that is what s/he expects. On the flip side `long % int` should be an `int` not a `long` IMHO.

Comment: BTW, even though `int->double` is lossless, that converison still violates the expectation that `(int)d==d`.  Personally I would have liked to see `(int)d`, if allowed at all, run-time assert that `d` was a whole number, since there are four plausible intended behaviors if `d` isn't a whole number. Requiring that the expression be written as either `d.intFloor`, `d.intTrunc`, `d.intRound`, or  `d.intRoundPeriodic` would make the programmer's intention clear and unambiguous.

Comment: I don't see how that is expected. `int -> double` is ok because `(double) i == i`.  `double -> int` is NOT ok as `(int) d == d` is unlikely to be right.

Comment: Should we chat?  I think my point was that I think that no pair of types should allow both direct comparisons and lossy casts, *even explicit ones* (though in the case of `int` and `double`, I think the cast rather than the comparison is 'bad'; if for big value `x`, `(11.0/10.0)+x-x` yields `1.0`, I'd regard that 1.0 as representing 11/10, albeit poorly.  By contrast, I'd say the integer 1 doesn't represents values other the multiplicative identity "badly"--it doesn't represent any other values *at all*.)