# Type conversion to double value in java

Tags: scjp

```
public class TypeConversion4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 2D + 2d + 2. + 2l + 2L + 2f + 2F + 2.f + 2.D;
        System.out.println(d); //prints 18.0
    }
}
```

how it prints 18.0. Can anyone provide some analysis.

Comment: where did you find the multiplication in the statement?

Comment: How many numbers are you adding?

Comment: @kittu It's second-grader's multiplication (by repeated addition of the same number).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight its not about multiplication. There are different types getting added

Comment: Not a problem - this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @kittu For the purposes of adding, a two is a two, no matter what type. You add nine of them, and you get eighteen. `double` trumps everything else in your expression, so you get your eighteen as a `double`

Comment: my bad as I got confused with the types getting added in the statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting between short,int,long,double,float in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516883/casting-between-short-int-long-double-float-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what's the problem? All these twos converted to the biggest type while summing up and then the result casted to double. But you can store 2 in long, int, double and float without any error. That means that all you have to do is to sum these 9 twos and come up with 18.0.

Comment: my bad as I got confused with the types getting added in the statement